# Fix multiple button click events in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, uibutton, uibuttonbaritem

Is there any way to prevent multiple button click events. In my application i have a scenario where multiple button events are getting called when the user taps the button continuously. Even after adding a loading indicator still sometimes its happening. Is there any generic solution to handle this ?

Comment: Set UIView.exclusiveTouch?

Comment: did not get your question , can you place your code

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman exclusive touch wont work i guess. In my the issue is that multiple taps are detected and the code inside is executed more than once causing multiple navigations.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh when i am tapping the button continuously multiple navigations are happening. I have added a loading indicator on button which covers the entire view so that user cant interact with UI. But still in some cases the button action executes more than once.

Comment: btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false when you tap on button

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Tried this in case of UIBarbutton item but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out different ways like enabling/disabling the button and enabling/disabling the UI (which is not at all recommended) the best way I feel is to use a "bool" variable to check the button clicked status.

```
`
var isButtonTapped = false
@IBAction func tapButton(sender: Any) {
    print("Tap")
    if(!isButtonTapped){
    //Perform your operations or page navigations. After the navigation operation set the bool value to true.
    isButtonTapped = true;
  }
}`
```

Make sure you reset the bool value to false when navigating away from the `ViewController`. You can do that in `ViewDidDisappear`.

Comment: You can reset this variable in viewWillAppear instead, Since it doesn't matter if you are away from the screen, just when you pop again to same screen this variable will get reset, this way no one will miss the variable since we always check viewWillAppear and DidLoad to check what initialisations are done for the VC

Answer (score 1):

when you click on the button in the click method put code

```
btnClick.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

it will not let user to click button anymore after you are done with the task put another line of code to enable the user to click on the button

```
btnClick.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you using UiButton

```
@IBAction func tapButton(sender: Any) {
    print("Tap")
    let btn = sender as! UIButton
    btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Try this if you using UIBarButtonItem

```
   leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backimage")!, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.toggleLeft))
    leftButton.title = "Back"

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton


@objc public func toggleLeft() {
    print("tap")
    leftButton.isEnabled = false
//   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What to do in case of UIBarbuttonitem. It does not have “isUserInteractionenabled” property

Comment: Okay will check it out